# AWS CFN Lambda not sending all messages to SQS

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I am new to AWS cloudformation and have an issue with my stacks.  I had these working but somewhere something went wrong.

Asume I have a ArtifactBucket stack with the zip files for my .Net core lambdas and the IAM user, role and KMS key.

I have this main stack which has a `Creator lambda` that will send a message to the `SQS Queue`. The processor function will receive that message and send it to SNS which then send me an email (see subscription)

It all deploys fine in AWS console but Im finding that when I invoke the lambda, I need to invoke it multiple times before I receive a message and some of the messages are lost. For example.. Ill send 5 messages one after another and only get message 4.

I suspect its a timeout issue on the lambda, and the Queue but I i'm struggling to pinpoint it down.

Do you spot anythign obvious I am either missing in this main template, or is there an issue with the Queue properties va the lambda time values?

```
   "DelaySeconds" : 0,
   "MessageRetentionPeriod" : 900,
   "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds" : 5,
   "VisibilityTimeout" : 120,
```

stack-template:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Template to create IntergrationQueue, Intergrator and use storage bucket",
  "Parameters": {
    "ArtifactBucketName": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "StorageBucketArn": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "JogDayIAMUserArn": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "JogDayIAMRoleArn": {
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "JogDayKMSKeyArn": {
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {  
    "DLQ": {
      "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",
      "Properties": {
        "KmsMasterKeyId": {
          "Ref": "JogDayKMSKeyArn"
        }
      }
    },
    "Queue": {
      "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",
      "DependsOn": "DLQ",
      "Properties": {
        "QueueName": "JogDayQueue",
        "DelaySeconds" : 0,
        "MessageRetentionPeriod" : 900,
        "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds" : 5,
        "VisibilityTimeout" : 120,
        "RedrivePolicy": {        
          "deadLetterTargetArn": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "DLQ",
              "Arn"
            ]
          },
          "maxReceiveCount" : 10          
        },
        "KmsMasterKeyId": {
          "Ref": "JogDayKMSKeyArn"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "jogday",
            "Value": "jogday"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "JogDayTopic": {
      "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic",      
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",
      "Properties": {
        "DisplayName": "JogDay topic",
        "KmsMasterKeyId" : {"Ref":"JogDayKMSKeyArn"},        
        "TopicName" : "JogDayEmailTopic",      
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "jogday",
            "Value": "jogday"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "JogDayQueuePolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy",
      "Description" : "Intergration Queue Policy",
      "DependsOn" : ["Queue","CreatorLambdaFunction"],
      "DeletionPolicy" : "Delete",      
      "Properties": {      
        "Queues": [{ "Ref":"Queue" }],        
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
              },
              "Action": [
                "SQS:SendMessage",
                "SQS:ReceiveMessage"
              ],
              "Resource": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "Queue",
                  "Arn"
                ]
              },
              "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                  "aws:SourceArn":{
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                      "CreatorLambdaFunction",
                      "Arn"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "JogDaySubscription": {
      "Type": "AWS::SNS::Subscription",      
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",
      "Properties": {      
        "TopicArn": {
          "Ref": "JogDayTopic"
        },
        "Endpoint": "some.email@gmail.com",
        "Protocol": "email"
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "JogDayTopic"
      ]
    },
    "CreatorLambdaFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",    
      "Properties": {
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore3.1",
        "FunctionName": "CreatorFunction",
        "Description": "Function that will take a message and send it to a SQS queue",
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": {
            "Ref": "ArtifactBucketName"
          },
          "S3Key": "CreatorFunction.zip"
        },
        "Handler": "CreatorFunction::CreatorFunction.Function::FunctionHandler",
        "Role": { "Ref": "JogDayIAMRoleArn" },
        "DeadLetterConfig": {
          "TargetArn": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "DLQ",
              "Arn"
            ]
          }
        },        
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "jogday",
            "Value": "jogday"
          }
        ],
        "Timeout": 120,        
        "KmsKeyArn": {
          "Ref": "JogDayKMSKeyArn"
        },
        "Environment": {
          "Variables": {
            "QueueName": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "Queue",
                "QueueName"
              ]
            },
            "DLQName": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "DLQ",
                "QueueName"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "CreatorLambdaFunctionInvokePermission": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",
      "Properties": {
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "CreatorLambdaFunction",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "Principal": {
          "Ref": "JogDayIAMUserArn"
        },
        "SourceAccount": {
          "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
        }
      }
    },
    "ProcessorLambdaFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",    
      "DependsOn" : ["Queue","DLQ","JogDayTopic"],
      "Properties": {
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore3.1",
        "FunctionName": "ProcessorFunction",
        "Description": "Function that will receive a message from sqs and send it to sns",
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": {
            "Ref": "ArtifactBucketName"
          },
          "S3Key": "ProcessorFunction.zip"
        },
        "Handler": "ProcessorFunction::ProcessorFunction.Function::FunctionHandler",        
        "Role": { "Ref": "JogDayIAMRoleArn" },
        "DeadLetterConfig": {
          "TargetArn": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "DLQ",
              "Arn"
            ]
          }
        },        
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "jogday",
            "Value": "jogday"
          }
        ],
        "Timeout": 120,
        "KmsKeyArn": {
          "Ref": "JogDayKMSKeyArn"
        },
        "Environment": {
          "Variables": {
            "QueueName": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "Queue",
                "QueueName"
              ]
            },
            "DLQName": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "DLQ",
                "QueueName"
              ]
            },
            "JogDayTopicArn": {"Ref" : "JogDayTopic" },         
            "JogDayTopicName": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "JogDayTopic",
                "TopicName"
              ]
            }       
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ProcessorLambdaFunctionInvokePermission": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",
      "Properties": {
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ProcessorLambdaFunction",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "Principal": {
          "Ref": "JogDayIAMUserArn"
        },
        "SourceAccount": {
          "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
        }
      }
    },
    "ProcessorLambdaEventSourceMapping": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",
      "DependsOn": ["ProcessorLambdaFunction","Queue"],
      "Properties": {
       "BatchSize" : 10,
       "Enabled" : true,
       "EventSourceArn" : {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "Queue",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "FunctionName" : {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "ProcessorLambdaFunction",
            "Arn"
          ]
        }     
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "QueueArn": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "Queue",
          "Arn"
        ]
      }
    },
    "DLQArn": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "DLQ",
          "Arn"
        ]
      }
    },
    "JogDayTopicName":{
     "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "JogDayTopic",
          "TopicName"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could be the issue with your lambda functions, not the template.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. The lambdas work fine as far as I can tell. The creator lambda simply send the messages to the queue and I can see the message do end up in the queue consistently.  The Processor function then fetches messages from the queue and send it to sns supposedly....  Repeatedly hitting the test button in AWS console eventually send the messages out but not all of them.. Tbh I did have this working liek clockwork a weekor two ago and fiddles with something as you do then it all fell over and I am a but stuck now.. :-)